# How to insert hyphens to each string in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string

I'm scraping a list but would like to convert the string to permalinks, which have hyphens between each word.

For example, I have a list:

```
['hi there', 'help please','with my problem']
```

I want it to end up like:

```
['hi-there','help-please', 'with-my-problem']
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only concerned with replacing a single space with a single hyphen, the other answers work great (particularly @kindall's which also makes sure you don't end up with leading or trailing hyphens).  But, if you want to transform `"foo    bar"` to `"foo-bar"`, they'll fail.

how about:

```
def replace_runs_of_whitespace_with_hyphen(word):
    return '-'.join(word.split())

hyphrases = [replace_runs_of_whitespace_with_hyphen(w) for w in phrases]
```

Or with regex (but this one could result in leading/trailing hyphens):

```
import re
re.sub(r'\s+', '-', word)
```

Comment: In this case I might just use a regex. In fact I'm kind of surprised not to see a regex-based solution here already!

Comment: Since you are using python, keeping your solution 'pythonic' seems a better idea than loading a regex engine for replacing simple spaces for dashes. The split + join solution seems better as of not leaving the python realm.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> spaces = ['hi there', 'help please','with my problem']
>>> hyphens = [s.replace(' ','-') for s in spaces]
>>> print hyphens
['hi-there','help-please', 'with-my-problem']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
phrases   = ['hi there', 'help please','with my problem']
hyphrases = [p.strip().replace(" ", "-") for p in phrases]
```

Comment: It's always fun when there are two simultaneous answers that are identical except for variable names, but even more so when the variable names rhyme, like "phrases" and "spaces". You and Brien need to have a rap battle to see who gets the rep. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
wordlist = ['hi there', 'help please', 'with my problem']
hyphenated_wordlist = map(lambda s: s.replace(' ', '-'), wordlist)
```